# Jquery selector where attribute ID not in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do we write a JQuery selector to select all the elements where the element's attribute value(considering `ID` also as an attribute) not in an array of strings? The array is of different length.

Comment: seems like a xy problem

Comment: Can you include `html` , array of values to exclude, and expected result at Question?

Answer (score 4):

Use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** for custom filtering purpose

```js
var ids = ['a', 'b', 'f'];

$('[id]').filter(function() {
  return ids.indexOf(this.id) == -1;
}).addClass('ele');
```

```css
.ele {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="a">a</span><span id="c">c</span><span id="b">b</span><span id="d">d</span><span id="e">e</span><span id="f">f</span>
```

---

Or use **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** for avoiding certain elments

```js
var ids = ['a', 'b', 'f'];

$('[id]').not('#' + ids.join(',#')).addClass('ele');
```

```css
.ele {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="a">a</span><span id="c">c</span><span id="b">b</span><span id="d">d</span><span id="e">e</span><span id="f">f</span>
```